# constexpr if and static_assert

Tags: c++, templates, constexpr, c++17, static-assert

[P0292R1 constexpr if](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0292r1.html) has been [included](https://herbsutter.com/2016/06/30/trip-report-summer-iso-c-standards-meeting-oulu/), on track for C++17. It seems useful (and can replace use of SFINAE), but a comment regarding `static_assert` being *ill-formed, no diagnostic required* in the false branch scares me:

```
Disarming static_assert declarations in the non-taken branch of a
constexpr if is not proposed.

void f() {
  if constexpr (false)
    static_assert(false);   // ill-formed
}

template<class T>
void g() {
  if constexpr (false)
    static_assert(false);   // ill-formed; no 
               // diagnostic required for template definition
}
```

I take it that it's completely forbidden to use `static_assert` inside constexpr if (at least the false / non-taken branch, but that in practice means it's not a safe or useful thing to do).

How does this come about from the standard text? I find no mentioning of `static_assert` in the proposal wording, and C++14 constexpr functions do allow `static_assert` (details at cppreference: [constexpr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr)).

Is it hiding in this new sentence (after 6.4.1) ? :

> When a constexpr if statement appears in a templated entity, 
>      during an instantiation of the enclosing template or generic lambda, 
>      a discarded statement is not instantiated.

From there on, I assume that it is also forbidden, no diagnostic required, to call other constexpr (template) functions which *somewhere* down the call graph may call `static_assert`.

**Bottom line:**

If my understanding is correct, doesn't that put a quite hard limit on the safety and usefulness of `constexpr if` as we would have to know (from documentation or code inspection) about any use of `static_assert`? Are my worries misplaced?

**Update:**

This code compiles without warning (clang head 3.9.0) but is to my understanding *ill-formed*, no diagnostic required. Valid or not?

```
template< typename T>
constexpr void other_library_foo(){
    static_assert(std::is_same<T,int>::value);
}

template<class T>
void g() {
  if constexpr (false)
    other_library_foo<T>(); 
}

int main(){
    g<float>();
    g<int>();
}
```

Comment: It's ill-formed because the condition is false. Not because it's inside a constexpr if...

Comment: @immibis. It's clear that this is all about the non-taken branch, so I don't understand what you mean specifically. Care to elaborate and interpret in terms of the bottom line question?

Comment: clang already implemented `if constexpr`. If you have any doubt, why not [try it on your own](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/8AmTzaSIIUi4M1kY)?

Comment: @cpplearner, Done that, but it does not add add much. The question is about what the *standard* say and its implications.

Comment: @JohanLundberg Well, *obviously* it's ill-formed if it's inside the taken branch.

Comment: Currently there's no standard or draft standard that contains the wording for `if constexpr`, and P0292R2, the paper that got accepted, is also not publicly available yet.

Comment: @immibis huh? Could you elaborate in an answer and clarify both obvious and non obvious parts?

Comment: @JohanLundberg A program containing `static_assert(false);` is ill-formed. But `constexpr if(false)` removes the code inside it. So the only thing that needs to be clarified is: when you combine both, does the `static_assert(false);` make the program ill-formed, or does the `constexpr if(false)` remove it before the compiler checks the `static_assert`?

Comment: @immibis: "*But constexpr if(false) removes the code inside it.*" That's the thing: it doesn't *remove* the code inside the not taken branch. It makes them into discarded statements. There's a difference.

Comment: @immibis, I did not consider that the deliberate compilation fail generated by static_assert(false) is via 'ill-formed', but it makes sense. What worries me is the unclarity regarding if it's active or not in the discared statements, and especially with 'no diagnostic required', and the bottom line question on how we can safely use constexpr with other peoples code.

Comment: `#define false ([](auto e) { return e; }(false))` might help.

Comment: There is now a paper about this problem: https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2593r0.html

Answer (score 46, accepted):

This is talking about a well-established rule for templates - the same rule that allows compilers to diagnose `template<class> void f() { return 1; }`. [[temp.res]/8](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res-8) with the new change bolded:

> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> - no valid specialization can be generated for a template **or a substatement
>     of a `constexpr if` statement ([stmt.if]) within a
>     template** and the template is not instantiated, or
> - [...]

No valid specialization can be generated for a template containing `static_assert` whose condition is nondependent and evaluates to `false`, so the program is ill-formed NDR.

`static_assert`s with a dependent condition that can evaluate to `true` for at least one type are not affected.

Comment: Thank you especially for the draft link. It makes sense as evaluating invalid templates can be arbitrarily hard.

Comment: Thanks again. Accepted. It's worth noting that the lines you quoted are in the original proposal I linked to, but I missed them.

Comment: Helper to make false template parameter dependet:template < typename > constexpr bool false_c = false;

Comment: However, and I don't know if that is a compiler bug or what is it, but, I had a function which different `if constexpr` statements that does depend on the template, and a `static_assert(false)` in the last `else` case. Since the `static_assert` won't be evaluated unless the other `if constexpr` statements fails, and thus, since the evaluation of the `static_assert` depends (indirectly) on the type, I think the code shouldn't be ill-formed, because there's "possible inputs" that doesn't trigger the `static_assert`.

Comment: @Peregring-lk It is ill-formed NDR, because "substatements of a constexpr if statements" are also affected. It is not (only) about the constexpr if statement as a whole.

Answer (score 38):

C++20 makes `static_assert` in the `else` branch of `if constexpr` much shorter now, because it allows template lambda parameters. So to avoid the ill-formed case, we can now define a lambda with a `bool` template non-type parameter that we use to trigger the `static_assert`. We immediately invoke the lambda with `()`, but since the lambda won't be instantiated if its `else` branch is not taken, the assertion will not trigger unless that `else` is actually taken:

```
template<typename T>
void g()
{
    if constexpr (case_1)
        // ...
    else if constexpr (case_2)
        // ...
    else
        []<bool flag = false>()
            {static_assert(flag, "no match");}();
}
```

Comment: In C++17 one can define a template function outside: `template<bool flag = false> void static_no_match() { static_assert(flag, "no match"); }` and then use `static_no_match()` in the `else` branch.

Comment: In C++17 we can just make the condition dependent on the template parameter, like `static_assert(!sizeof(T), "no match");`. [See it live](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c44a266099961a6c)

Comment: "else" branch looks ugly with this lambda.

Comment: @korst1k You should be able to macro it. Like `STATIC_FAIL("no match");`

Comment: I’m not at all sure that this evades the IFNDR rule: it’s still the case that no valid specialization of the substatement exists, although one would have to reason out whether the validity of the chosen specialization of the lambda’s `operator()` counted for that purpose.

Comment: This answer is referenced in the [P2593 committee paper](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2593r0.html) where it's described as "terrible and wrong". That paper has been accepted into C++23 and will allow `static_assert(false)`.

Answer (score 10):

***Edit:*** I'm keeping this self-answer with examples and more detailed explanations of the misunderstandings that lead to this questions. The short answer by T.C. is strictly enough.

After rereading the proposal and on `static_assert` in the [current draft](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2016/n4594.pdf), and  I conclude that my worries were misguided. First of all, the emphasis here should be on template *definition*.

> ill-formed; no diagnostic required for template definition

If a template is *instantiated*, any `static_assert` fire as expected. This presumably plays well with the statement I quoted:

> ... a discarded statement is not instantiated.

This is a bit vague to me, but I conclude that it means that *templates* occurring in the discarded statement will not be instantiated. Other code 
however must be syntactically valid. A `static_assert(F)`, [where F is false, either literally or a constexpr value] inside a discarded `if constexpr` clause will thus still 'bite' when the template containing the `static_assert` is instantiated. Or (not required, at the mercy of the compiler) already at declaration if it's known to always be false.

Examples: ([live demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/I78eDUSk5sDjepEK))

```
#include <type_traits>

template< typename T>
constexpr void some_library_foo(){
    static_assert(std::is_same<T,int>::value);
}

template< typename T>
constexpr void other_library_bar(){
    static_assert(std::is_same<T,float>::value);
}

template< typename T>
constexpr void buzz(){
    // This template is ill-formed, (invalid) no diagnostic required,
    // since there are no T which could make it valid. (As also mentioned
    // in the answer by T.C.).
    // That also means that neither of these are required to fire, but
    // clang does (and very likely all compilers for similar cases), at
    // least when buzz is instantiated.
    static_assert(! std::is_same<T,T>::value);
    static_assert(false); // does fire already at declaration
                          // with latest version of clang
}

template<class T, bool IntCase>
void g() {
  if constexpr (IntCase){
    some_library_foo<T>();

    // Both two static asserts will fire even though within if constexpr:
    static_assert(!IntCase) ;  // ill-formed diagnostic required if 
                              // IntCase is true
    static_assert(IntCase) ; // ill-formed diagnostic required if 
                              // IntCase is false

    // However, don't do this:
    static_assert(false) ; // ill-formed, no diagnostic required, 
                           // for the same reasons as with buzz().

  } else {
    other_library_bar<T>();
  }      
}

int main(){
    g<int,true>();
    g<float,false>();

    //g<int,false>(); // ill-formed, diagnostic required
    //g<float,true>(); // ill-formed, diagnostic required
}
```

The standard text on `static_assert` is remarkably short. In standardese, it's a way to make the program *ill-formed* with diagnostic (as @immibis also pointed out):

> 7.6 ... If the value of the expression when so converted is true, the declaration has no effect. Otherwise, the program is ill-formed, and
>   the resulting diagnostic message (1.4) shall include the text of the
>   string-literal, if one is supplied ...

Comment: A few years passed, do you happen to know a better solution? `static_assert(IntCase)` is very inconvenient for complex nest if-else.  I really wish to call `static_assert(false)` within some `else`.

Comment: The phrase "ill-formated" is ill-formed. (No pun intended)

Answer (score 7):

The most concise way I've come across to work-around this ([at least in current compilers](https://godbolt.org/z/YcEM3vbbY)) is to use `!sizeof(T*)` for the condition, [detailed by Raymond Chen here](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553). It's a little weird, and doesn't technically get around the ill-formed problem, but at least it's short and doesn't require including or defining anything. A small comment explaining it may assist readers:

```cpp
template<class T>
void g() {
  if constexpr (can_use_it_v<T>) {
    // do stuff
  } else {
    // can't use 'false' -- expression has to depend on a template parameter
    static_assert(!sizeof(T*), "T is not supported");
  }
}
```

The point of using `T*` is to still give the proper error for incomplete types.

I also came across this [discussion in the old isocpp mailing list](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/g/std-proposals/c/d2ADcbygYn4/m/jNtpL2GpBgAJ) which may add to this discussion. Someone there brings up the interesting point that doing this kind of conditional `static_assert` is not always the best idea, since it cannot be used to SFINAE-away overloads, which is sometimes relevant.

Comment: It’s still IFNDR to have a branch of a constexpr if that’s invalid for all instantiations.

Comment: Is it an ill-formed expression that all the compilers chose to not implement? [seems to work as expected on all 3 major ones](https://godbolt.org/z/YcEM3vbbY). I believe by making it type-dependent, it delays the `static_assert` until after `if constexpr` is resolved.

Comment: That’s what “no diagnostic required” means—the implementation might or might not do enough analysis to determine that it’s always invalid.  “Delaying” the `static_assert` may be a thing that can happen in (today’s) real compilers, but it doesn’t mean anything formally at all.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my understanding! You're saying that some day, a compiler may do a value range analysis earlier and see that it is always false. Could go either way I guess, with either the implementers wanting to do more analysis (like they do in some of the UB cases), or the committee specifying that this is okay (or an alternative). The desire to write asserts like this seem to come up reasonably often.

Comment: The committee has [considered](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/p1830r1.pdf) providing an *idiom* here.  They’ve also informally considered restricting the scope of the problem, because technically a compiler can also *arbitrarily miscompile* a program that does this.

Answer (score 3):

This has been found to be a defect, [CWG 2518](https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2518.html). Static asserts now are ignored in template declarations, so now are delayed until instantiation. Failing static asserts are no longer ill-formed no diagnostic required during template resolution.

It is being applied to all C++ modes [in clang](https://reviews.llvm.org/rG00e2098bf49f0ed45b3b8c22894cd3ac9a530e0f) and [GCC 13](https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=commit;h=9944ca17c0766623bce260684edc614def7ea761).

Answer (score 1):

A comma expression can make the `static_assert` condition dependent on template arguments:

```cpp
  #include <type_traits>

  template<typename T>
  constexpr int func(T x)
  {
    if constexpr(std::is_same_v<T, int>){
      return x;
    } else {
      static_assert((sizeof(T), false), "Bad template argument");
      return 0;
    }
   }
```

Or you can make a dependent expression which is always false:

```
      static_assert(sizeof(T) == 0, "Bad template argument");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your self-answer and possibly the one by T.C. are not quite correct.

First of all, the sentence "Both two static asserts will fire even though within `if constexpr`" is not correct. They won't because the `if constexpr` condition depends on a template parameter.
You can see that if you comment out the `static_assert(false)` statements and the definition of `buzz()` in your example code: `static_assert(!IntCase)` won't fire and it will compile.

Furthermore, things like `AlwaysFalse<T>::value` or `! std::is_same_v<T, T>` [are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53945490/how-to-assert-that-a-constexpr-if-else-clause-never-happen) (and have no effect) inside a discarded `constexpr if`, **even if there's no `T` for which they evaluate to true**.
I think that "no valid specialization can be generated" is bad wording in the standard (unless cppreference is wrong; then T.C. would be right). It should say "*could* be generated", with further clarification of what is meant by "could".

This is related to the question whether `AlwaysFalse<T>::value` and `! std::is_same_v<T, T>` [are equivalent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57812038/if-constexpr-and-dependent-false-static-assert-is-ill-formed) in this context (which is what the comments to this answer are about).
I would argue that they are, since it's "can" and not "could" and both are false for all types at the point of their instantiation.
The crucial difference between `std::is_same` and the non-standard wrapper here is that the latter could theoretically be specialized (thanks, cigien, for pointing this out and providing the link).

The question whether ill-formed NDR or not also crucially depends on whether the template is instantiated or not, just to make that entirely clear.

Comment: Would you care to explain your point more? Most of the answers in the question you link to conclude that a non std wrapper is required. Such as https://stackoverflow.com/a/53945555/1149664

Comment: No, as far as I see they only ever speak of a "type-dependent" expression, i.e. an expression that depends on T.

Comment: It works pretty nice, without warning on gcc or clang. https://wandbox.org/permlink/b7DMBGyaFj7V2Nc7

Comment: This is not correct. It would be fine if specializations of `is_same_v` could exist, but *"The behavior of a program that adds specializations for is_same or is_same_v (since C++17) is undefined."*.

Comment: @cigien It's not about adding specializations for `is_same`. The standard one serves this purpose just fine. (So would any other expression that always yields false but depends on `T`.)

Comment: Actually, it's ifndr if it could *only* yield false. There has to be at least the *possibility* of it being true, which in the case of `std::is_same<T,T>` its not.

Comment: @cigien Do you have a source for that? (There's some more discussion in the accepted answer to the thread I linked to in my answer. Maybe it would fit better there and I would adjust my wording accordingly or delete my post.)

Comment: @cigien I think I understand your point of view now. I would still argue that "no valid specialization could be generated" for the (outer) template, whether specializations for the template in the expression can exist or not (because specializations afterwards or in another place have no effect on the instantiation; you would need a (never used) specialization of a hypothetical `AlwaysFalse` which actually *isn't* false to conform to your reading, wouldn't you?). I edited my answer to clarify that.

Comment: Hmm, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812126/8372853)

Comment: @cigien Thanks. I would say, though, that we unfortunately still don't have a reference to the standard which entirely clarifies this (if the possibility is enough or not). I edited my answer again to elaborate a bit more. Furthermore, you could argue that without an actual specialization yielding `true` there's not even the possibility.

Answer (score -3):

My solution is:

```
if constexpr (is_same_v<T,int>)
  // ...
else if constexpr (is_same_v<T,float>)
  // ...
else
  static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, void> && !std::is_same_v<T, void>, "Unsupported element type.");
```

Comment: This is "ill formed, no diagnostics required". Read other answers why.