# Static_assert inside if constexpr not discarded

Tags: c++, instantiation, constexpr, static-assert, if-constexpr

The following `static_assert` should be discarded being in the false branch of `if constexpr`, yet compilation fails due to assert failure:

```
#include <type_traits>                                                                                                                                                                              

template <class T>                                                                                                                                                                                  
constexpr bool f() {                                                                                                                                                                                
  if constexpr (std::is_same<T, int>::value) return true;                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
  else static_assert(false, "message");                                                                                                                                                             
}                                                                                                                                                                                                   

int main () {                                                                                                                                                                                       
  if constexpr (f<int>()) return 1;                                                                                                                                                                 
  return 0;                                                                                                                                                                                         
}
```

I'd expect that the discarded branch of `if constexpr` wouldn't be evaluated because `f` is instantiated with type `int`.

Compiled with Gcc 7.2 (-std=c++17)

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/64354296/856199 for the easiest way to do this in C++20.