# Stop compilation if `if constexpr` does not match

Tags: c++, if-constexpr

I have a template function that checks the type of a template argument with an `if constexpr` such as

```cpp
template <typename T>
bool something(T arg) {
  if constexpr (std::is_integral_v<T>) {
    return true;
  } else {
    // What can I write here so that something<double>(0.0) does not compile?
  }

  return false;
}
```

How can I make the code fail to compile if none of my `if constexpr`s match?

Comment: Add an static assert

Comment: `if constexpr` doesn't make sense here.  `static_assert(std::is_integral_v<T>)` seems like it would be a simpler approach.

Comment: @MilesBudnek *"if none of my if constexprs match"* This implies OP has several `if constexpr`s chained in their actual code.

Comment: Having multiple type-checks like that is not considered good code, and could even be a sign of bad design. Perhaps you should consider overloading or specialization instead?

Comment: @Some How is it considered not good code? By whom? This is just another way of writing a series of template specialisations for a fixed set of types. You could even argue this is a more natural expression of the concept (it's not entirely equivalent though).

Comment: @rubenvb It can quickly become a very tangled mess that is hard to read, understand and maintain. In C++ there are cleaner and simpler solutions to overcome or work around the lack of introspection in the language.

Comment: @Oblivion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304847/constexpr-if-and-static-assert

Comment: It seems that cannot use static_assert and if constexpr simultaneously

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The soltuion is to use `static_assert`.

But we can't simply do `static_assert(false, "whatever");` in the `else` branch, because since the condition doesn't depend on the template parameter, assertion might fire early (when the compiler first sees your function body, even if the `else` branch is never actually taken).

The condition of `static_assert` has to somehow depend on `T`, to delay the assertion check until your template is instantinated.

This is what I've been using:

```cpp
template <auto A, typename...> auto value = A;
```

```cpp
if constexpr (foo)
{
    ...
}
else if constexpr (bar)
{
    ...
}
else
{
    static_assert(value<false, T>, "Invalid template parameter.");
}
```

---

Note that if you only have **one** `if constexpr` (rather than an `if` `else if` chain), then none of that is needed.

Simply move the condition from `if` to a `static_assert` and remove the `if`.

Comment: There seems a problem at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304847/constexpr-if-and-static-assert
So why the code in that weblink wrong?

Comment: @vrqq That code creates an `if constexpr` branch that **can't** be valid, ever, making it ill-formed NDR. But in my code, the last branch can be made valid by specializing `value` to be true.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question.

I'm not an expert, but this worked for me and it doesn't require any extra definitions.

```
static_assert(! std::is_void<std::void_t<T>>::value , "")
```

First, `std::void_t<T>` always returns void type for any T.
Then, `std::is_void<T>::value` is true if T is void.
So this is a way to get true/false from any type T.

Should work from C++17 onward.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another answer, although the idea is the same.

You can just use this in your else branch:

`static_assert(!std::is_same_v<T,T>, "")`

Kinda less readable but hey it works :)

Comment: I think technically this is ill-formed NDR, exactly like `static_assert(false)`, because you're not allowed to specialize `is_same_v<T, T>` to be true. If you were to write your own class, an exact copy of `std::is_same_v`, then it would become legal, because your own classes *can* be specialized.