# cannot convert 'std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>' to 'int' in return return value;

Tags: c++

The keyGenerator should check which data type is given as an argument and convert it to an integer. It works for float and double, but when trying to convert a string to an integer, it does not work. Do you have any ideas why this might be happening?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

template<typename T>
class KeyValueKnot
{
public:
    T value;
    int key;
    KeyValueKnot *next;

    KeyValueKnot(T value)
    {
        this->value = value;
        this->key = keyGenerator(value);
        this->next = NULL;
    }
    int keyGenerator(T value)
    {
        if (typeid(value) == typeid(std::string))
        {
            return (int) generateNumberFromString(value);
        }
        else if (typeid(value) == typeid(double))
        {
            return static_cast<int>(value);
        }
        else if (typeid(value) == typeid(int))
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Unknown type" << std::endl;
        }
        
    }
    
    int generateNumberFromString(string str)
    {
        int result = 0;
        for (char c : str)
        {
            result += static_cast<int>(c);
        }
        return result;
    }
    
};
```

Comment: Because `float`s and `double`s implicitly convert to to `int`. `std::string` does not. Converting a string to an `int` has measurable cost and many failure cases, so the compiler forces you to acknowledge that you wish to pay this cost and have code in place to handle the failure cases.

Comment: The conditions have to be spelled as [`else`] `if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, YourType>)`, otherwise all brances will be validated even if they're never taken. The fallback branch should use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56466352/2752075) instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: `if (typeid(value) == typeid(std::string))` --  `else if (typeid(value) == typeid(double))` -- You cannot use runtime checks like this to check for the template type.  Using these typese of checks does not do a compile-time branching of the code.

Comment: Disagree. You can do runtime checks like this, but it's generally better if the compiler does the job at compile time and can optimize out the now-dead code for the other cases.

Comment: Side note: when a function promises to return a value it must ALWAYS return a value. The `else` case does not return a value and invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub). The program may not function as intended. Worse, it may function as intended during your testing and then raise an army of vengeful machines against humanity shortly after deployment.

Comment: Your C++ textbook will explain how to specialize templates. This is the correct way to do something like what the shown code is trying to do, cleaner and without the ugly `if` mucking with typeids.

Comment: @user4581301 I would think as soon as you pass a `double` into the template, the compiler will trip up on the `generateNumberFromString`, because all branches will be evaluated.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, you have me there in this case and probably most cases. The checks are fine, what comes after will fail.

Comment: [Yes, a compiler error when double is used](https://godbolt.org/z/8M93KhK8q).

Comment: @OP -- *It works for float and double*, No it doesn't work anymore.  Try `double` again after adding the `generateNumberFromString` code.  It looks like you didn't test `double` after making the coding change.  Having said that, I wonder if there is a duplicate for this type of error, since you are not the first person to attempt to use `if/else` and `typeid`, hoping the compiler will choose the correct branch at compile-time.

Answer (score 1):

Your `if`s are evaluated at *runtime*, so all branches need to be valid at *compile-time*.

However, when `T` is not `std::string` then the expression `generateNumberFromString(value)` is not valid for any type of `T` that is not *implicitly* convertible to `std::string`.

And, when `T` is `std::string`, the expressions `static_cast<int>(value)` and `return value;` are not valid because `std::string` can't be converted to `int`.

To fix this, you need to use [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_if) instead (or SFINAE or template specializations if you are using a pre-C++17 compiler), so the `if` branches are evaluated at *compile-time* instead, allowing unused branches to be removed by the compiler, eg:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
inline constexpr bool always_false_v = false;

int keyGenerator(T value)
    {
        if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, std::string>)
        {
            return (int) generateNumberFromString(value);
        }
        else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, double>)
        {
            return static_cast<int>(value);
        }
        //else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, int>)
        else if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<T, int>) 
        {
            return value;
        }
        else
        {
            static_assert(always_false_v<T>, "Unknown type");
        }
    }
```

See [How can I create a type-dependent expression that is always false?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200311-00/?p=103553) for an explanation of why `always_false_v` is needed in the `static_assert` (hint: without it, the code will *always* fail with an assert error!).