# Select unary vs. binary std::transform function overload automatically based on callable's signature

Tags: c++, lambda, dry, template-meta-programming, compile-time

[std::transform](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) provides overloads which take either a unary (one argument) or binary (two argument) callable operation (typically a lambda).

I would like to pass my desired callable as an argument to a parent function, and use a compile-time (e.g. template metaprogramming) approach to automatically select which of the `std::transform` overloads gets used, based on whether the passed callable has a function signature with one or two arguments.

Here is the desired approach expressed in (not yet working) code:

```
#include <algorithm>

auto UnaryOp = [](const auto& src) { return src; };                                 // simple copy
auto BinaryOp = [](const auto& src1, const auto& src2) {return src1 + src2; };      // accumulate

auto GenericTransformer = [](auto src, auto dst, auto operation) {  // operation is unary OR binary

    /* unrelated code */

        // need to chose this one:
    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), dst.begin(), operation);
        // or this one:
    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), dst.begin(), dst.begin(), operation);
        // depending on whether unary or binary operation is passed in 'operation' argument

    /* unrelated code */

};

int main() {
    std::vector<int> source_vec(100);
    std::vector<int> dest_vec(100);
    GenericTransformer(source_vec, dest_vec, UnaryOp);  // i.e. copy source to destination
    GenericTransformer(source_vec, dest_vec, BinaryOp); // i.e. accumulate source into destination
}
```

Here I have defined two lambda operations - one unary and one binary (`UnaryOp` and `BinaryOp`) – which are passed to the `GenericTransformer()` from `main()`.

Within `GenericTransformer()`, what compile-time magic can I use to automatically select which of the two `std::transform()` calls gets made based on the function signature of the `operation` argument?

NOTE: this is a simplified case for example purposes.  I would prefer not to have to split `GenericTransformer()` into two separate functions (a unary one and a binary one), as that would result in a lot of duplication of code not shown here.  Sticking to the DRY philosophy!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With C++17 you can mix `if constexpr` and [`std::is_invocable`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable):

```
if constexpr (std::is_invocable_v<
    decltype(operation),  decltype(*src.begin())>) {
    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), dst.begin(), operation);
}
else {
    std::transform(src.begin(), src.end(), dst.begin(), dst.begin(), operation);
}
```

You could also check that `operation` is valid in the second case but that would require an extra `else` branch to avoid silencing compile-time errors when (neither branch is valid), and this would require some [`always_false` shenanigan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304847/constexpr-if-and-static-assert).

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica That's right, I've removed the branch and use a `else` instead of `else if` to avoid silently ignoring the `if`.

Comment: Thanks @Holt... yes, the std::transform template will cause compile time error if an unsupported operation is passed, so the simple if/else case covers all the bases.