# if constexpr not-taken branch doesn't need to be valid, sure?

Tags: c++, if-constexpr

I'm testing the code below:

```cpp
#define TO_STRING(X) #X

#define TEST(X, Y) namespace Y { constexpr std::string_view name{#X}, raw_value{TO_STRING(X)};\
constexpr bool defined {name!=raw_value}; constexpr bool has_value{raw_value!=""}; }

#define A
#define B 1

TEST(A, a);
TEST(B, b);
TEST(C, c);

int main()
{
    if constexpr (a::defined && a::has_value) {
        std::cout << a::name << " = " << a::raw_value << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << a::name << " not defined or have no value\n";
    }
    if constexpr (b::defined && b::has_value) {
        std::cout << b::name << " = " << b::raw_value << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << b::name << " not defined or have no value\n";
    }
    if constexpr (c::defined && c::has_value) {
        std::cout << c::name << " = " << c::raw_value << '\n';
    } else {
        std::cout << c::name << " not defined or have no value\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which produces the following output:

> ```
> A not defined or have no value
> B = 1
> C not defined or have no value
> ```

If I modify the `TEST` adding a new function:

```
#define TEST(X, Y) namespace Y { constexpr std::string_view name{#X}, raw_value{TO_STRING(X)};\
constexpr bool defined {name!=raw_value}; constexpr bool has_value{raw_value!=""};\
constexpr auto value() { if constexpr (defined && has_value) return X; else return; } }
```

I was expecting the compiler to ignore the `return X` statement while expanding `TEST(C, c)` macro, it reports an error instead:

> ```
> error: use of undeclared identifier 'C'
> TEST(C, c);
>      ^
> ```

Referencing an undeclared identifier is absolutely ill formed but I was expecting the compiler to ignore it because I thought that `if constexpr` untaken branches didn't need to be well formed. Is there a way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: "*I thought that if constexpr untaken branches didn't need to be well formed*" - this is incorrect.  [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38304847/3282436) shows another concrete use case that comes up from time-to-time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> #### [`[stmt.if]/2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stmt.if#2)
>
> If the value of the ... condition is false, the first substatement *[aka the first branch]* is a *discarded statement*, otherwise the second substatement, if present, is a discarded statement.
> **During the instantiation of an enclosing templated entity** ..., if the condition is not value-dependent after its instantiation, **the discarded substatement (if any) is not instantiated**.

<sup>(bold mine)</sup>

This explains the behavior of `if constexpr` inside of templates. Since nothing else is said about it, its behavior outside of templates matches the behavior of the plain `if`.

Now, if you're thinking about making your function a template by adding an unused template parameter, it's not going to work so easily:

> #### [`[temp.res.general]/6.1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#res.general-6.1)
>
> The program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required, if:
>
> — no valid specialization can be generated for a template **or a substatement of a constexpr if statement** within a template and the template is not instantiated

<sup>(bold mine)</sup>