# constexpr-if(false) vs two phase name lookup

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, language-lawyer, if-constexpr

```cpp
void func4();

template<typename T>
void test(T t) {
    if constexpr(false) {
        func1(t);      // #1 OK
        //func2();     // #2 Error
        //::func3(t);  // #3 Error
        ::func4(t);    // #4 OK??
    }
}

int main() {
  test(0);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/K1c7WW8sG

TLDR: Is #4 well-defined or something else?

If I understand correctly,

- #1 is ok because `func1(t)` is dependent on `t` and might need to look up with ADL in 2nd phase, which doesn't happen because `if constexpr(false)` is not dependent and is not instantiated (see [Does "if constexpr(something false)" ALWAYS omit template instantiation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56334957/does-if-constexprsomething-false-always-omit-template-instantiation)),
- #2 is error because `func2()` is not dependent and needs a declaration in 1st phase,
- #3 is error because qualified `::func3(t)` is not dependent and needs a declaration in namespace `::` in 1st phase.

However, a declaration of `::func4` exists but with a signature that cannot be called at #4. All three big compilers accept it. I wonder if it is well-defined or something else.

Comment: Dupes: [constexpr if and static_assert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38304847/constexpr-if-and-static-assert) and [if constexpr not-taken branch doesn't need to be valid, sure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67167379/if-constexpr-not-taken-branch-doesnt-need-to-be-valid-sure)

Comment: Looks ill-formed NDR on the surface, but I'm surprised Clang doesn't diagnose this, as it otherwise tries to be strict about it. Maybe it doesn't want to attempt an incomplete overload "resolution" in general, and it not catching the argument count mismatch is just a side effect of that?

Comment: Reclosing. In retrospect, T.C. quotes the the most relevant clause. The crux of the matter is that the condition of the if constexpr doesn't matter. Even if it's guarnteed to be a discarded branch in all instantiations, the fact it can never contain a valid sub-statment makes it ill-formed; ndr.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica Thank you. Can you please pointer out if I am understanding it correctly now: #1 is well-defined because there could be a potential T=Tx makes it valid via ADL, even it is not valid for instantiation of T=int, and even there isn't one Tx in the whole program. #4 is ill-formed; ndr, because there can never be a potential T=Ty makes it valid.

Comment: That's as I understand it, yes