# Expansion of multiple parameter packs of types and integer values

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I **previously** asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73008959/2369597), which basically asked how do I change the following "pseudo code" to get the result the comments show:

```
struct MyStructure {

  std::array<pair<TYPE, int>> map {
    { int, 1 },
    { char, 2 },
    { double, 4 },
    { std::string, 8 }
  };

  template <typename T>
  auto operator=(const T &arg) {
    // Depending on the type of 'arg', I want to write a certain value to the member variable 'type_'
  }
  int type_ = 0;
};

int main() {

  MyStructure myStruct;
  myStruct = 1;             // Should cause 1 to be stored in member 'type_ '
  myStruct = "Hello world"; // Should cause 8 to be stored in member 'type_'
}
```

**I obtained a suitable answer in the linked question**, but now I have a different requirement.  I would like to be able to pass the possible integer values and types through as template arguments, and somehow expand them to auto-generate the specialisations as given on the accepted answer.  The reason for this is that `MyStructure` now has to specify the possible values that can be assigned to it, so the 'hard coded' solution approach would not work.

My first thought was to create a new class that `MyStructure` derives from, that takes the types parameter pack and the ints parameter pack...

```
template<typename... Types, int...ints> 
class Base_Type  {
// Somehow expand the packs to generate the specialisations
};

template<typename... Types, int...ints>
struct MyStructure : Base_Type<Types..., ints...> {
// 
  template <typename T>
  auto operator=(const T &arg) {
    // Check T is within 'Types'
    // Query Base_Type for the T specialization to get the corresponding integer value to write to 'type_'
  }
  int type_ = 0;

};
```

Unfortunately I can't see how to do this because - for a start - I can only apparently have one template parameter pack:

```
'Types': if a class template has a template parameter pack it must appear at the end of the template parameter list
```

Is what I want to achieve here possible with C++ 17?

Comment: Do you actually need custom numbers? Those look like powers of two.

Comment: A variadic list of types can be represented as a tuple. This is common. Generic definition of the form `template<typename T, int ...ints>` and a specialization of the form `template<typename ...Types, int ...ints> struct BaseType<std::tuple<Types...>, ints...>`. The template gets references as, for example, `BaseType<std::tuple<char, int>, 1, 2>`. This solves the problem of defining the parameters. It would be possible to concoct a "recursively-inheriting" `BaseType` that will produce the same mapping as my original answer, but in a completely different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to *generate* specializations, but you don't actually need those.

It's not possible to have more than one template parameter pack per class template, so we'll have to work with a single one, with a helper struct that combines both a type and its index into a single type.

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, int I>
struct Type
{
    using type = T;
    static constexpr int value = I;
};

template <typename ...P>
struct Foo
{
    int index = 0;

    template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<T, typename P::type> || ...), std::nullptr_t> = nullptr>
    Foo &operator=(const T &)
    {
        (void)((std::is_same_v<T, typename P::type> ? (index = P::value, true) : false) || ...);
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<Type<int, 10>, Type<float, 20>> x;
    x = 42;
    std::cout << x.index << '\n'; // 10
    x = 42.f;
    std::cout << x.index << '\n'; // 20
    // x = 42L; // Error.
}
```

`(X || ...)` is a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold). It repeats `X` multiple times, once per element of `P`. Every use of `P` in `X` is replaced with its i-th element.

We use it as a poor man's loop. When the types match and `? :` returns true, the loop stops.

The cast to `(void)` silences the "unused result" warning.

Comment: I'd probably use `std::disjunction_v` instead but +1

Comment: Thank you!  I have a follow up on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73013147/2369597) if you could advise please.