# Extract all TYPE from a parameter pack of <TYPE, INT> and forward to base type

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

From this [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73012066/2369597), **I was kindly provided** with the following code, which enables me to set the member `index` to a specific value depending on what type has been passed in.

```
template <typename T, int I>
struct Type {
  using type = T;
  static constexpr int value = I;
};

template <typename ...P>
struct Foo {
  int index = 0;

  template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<(std::is_same_v<T, typename P::type> || ...), std::nullptr_t> = nullptr> // Only enable if type that has been passed s
  Foo& operator=(const T&) {
    (void)((std::is_same_v<T, typename P::type> ? (index = P::value, true) : false) || ...);
    return *this;
  }
};

int main() {

  Foo<Type<int, 10>, Type<float, 20>> x;
  x = 42;
  std::cout << x.index << '\n'; // 10
  x = 42.f;
  std::cout << x.index << '\n'; // 20
  //x = 42L; // Error.
}
```

I now need `Foo` to derive from `variant`, passing the TYPE members of the parameter pack through.  So, in the code above, `Foo` should derive from `std::variant<int, float>`.

Is it possible to obtain the `TYPE`s from the parameter pack passed through and forward them onto `variant` in C++17 ?

Comment: `std::variant<typename P::type...>`. Also note that `std::variant` stores its own index, so probably shouldn't store another of your own, and instead compute it on the fly from variant's one.

Comment: you shouldn't derive from standard library types in general. Why do you need to derive rather than having a member?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, thanks that works.  Please post as an answer if you wouid like your reward.  Alan, it's a long story, and I'm aware its not optimal.

Comment: I don't think it's worthy of an answer, since it's the very basic use of parameter packs.