# Constexpr matching wide vs narrow strings types

Tags: c++, c++20, constexpr, c++-concepts, fmt

I have a wrapper around fmt that prints to visual studio debug output. I tried to add wide string support:

```cpp
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void fmt(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    auto out = fmt::format(arg, args...);
    if constexpr (std::is_same<Arg, char8_t*>)
        OutputDebugStringA(out.c_str());
    else if constexpr (std::is_same<Arg, char16_t*>)
        OutputDebugStringW(out.c_str());
    else
        static_assert(false);
}
```

But it seems are a lot of different types you might want to match together

`const char (&)[N]`, `const char*`, `char*` etc.

How do you handle this elegantly?

Comment: Not sure, but maybe using [std::is_convertible](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_convertible) instead of `std::is_same` can help ?

Comment: Instead of creating `OutputDebugStringA()` and `OutputDebugStringW()`, why not have a single `OutputDebugString<CharT>()`?  That pushes down another level - you'll either end up at a generic level of standard library (e.g. `basic_ostream<CharT>`) or somewhere you can specialize the different versions.

Comment: How about 2 overloads? one with `std::format_string` one with `std::format_wstring`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if constexpr` and `static_assert` don't work that well together (until C++23).
This example is a C++17 version with SFINAE (for C++20 use concepts).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <type_traits>
#include <fmt/format.h>
#include <fmt/xchar.h>

// static_assert and `constexpr if` don't match, you will always get static_asset failure
// (up to C++20)

template<typename type_t, typename... args_t>
auto my_fmt(type_t&& fmt, args_t&&... args) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<std::string_view, type_t>, std::string>
{
    // for runtime format strings use vformat and make_format_args
    auto output = fmt::vformat(std::string_view{ fmt }, fmt::make_format_args(args...));
    return output;
}

template<typename type_t, typename... args_t>
auto my_fmt(type_t&& fmt, args_t&&... args) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_constructible_v<fmt::v10::wstring_view, type_t>, std::wstring>
{
    std::wstring output = fmt::vformat(fmt::v10::wstring_view{ fmt }, fmt::make_wformat_args(args...));
    return output;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << " char : " << my_fmt("{}", 42) << "\n";
    std::wcout << " wchar_t : " << my_fmt(L"{}", 42) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've just been looking at how to do `if constexpr` `static_assert` in C++20 https://stackoverflow.com/a/64354296/11998382 How do you do it in C++23? https://godbolt.org/z/88rMbzjEo

Comment: Oh I just need to use the latest versions https://godbolt.org/z/8jEs93rPq

Answer (score 1):

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void fmt(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
{
    if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<Arg, const char*>)
        OutputDebugStringA(arg);
    else if constexpr (std::is_convertible_v<Arg, const wchar_t*>)
        OutputDebugStringW(arg);
    else 
        []<bool flag = false>(){
        static_assert(flag, "no match");}();
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/c94nWq5vs